# Invertibility in Markov processes

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, self-learning

In literature, it is written for Discrete Time Markov processes, if there exists unique stationary distribution $\Pi$, then this distribution can be obtained by following formula
$$
\Pi^\top = \mathbf1^\top (P-I+\mathbf1\mathbf1^\top)^{-1},
$$
where $P$ is transition probability matrix and $I$ is identity and $\mathbf1$ is all ones vector. How can we guarantee that $(P-I+\mathbf1\mathbf1^\top)$ is always invertible? They usually mention it, but I have never seen proof. How this can be proven?

Comment: What is $\mathbf{11}^T$?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy all ones matrix $n\times n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $P$ has a unique stationary distribution $\Pi$ and

\begin{equation}
(P-I+\mathbf1\mathbf1^\top)x=0\label{eq:1}\tag1
\end{equation}

for some vector $x$. In particular,

\begin{equation}
\Pi^\top P=\Pi^\top
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\Pi^\top\mathbf1=1\,.
\end{equation}

Multiplying Equation \ref{eq:1} by $\Pi^\top$ and substituting the last two identities yields

\begin{align}
0
&=\Pi^\top(P-I+\mathbf1\mathbf1^\top)x=(\Pi^\top P)x-\Pi^\top x+(\Pi^\top\mathbf1)\mathbf1^\top x=\Pi^\top x-\Pi^\top x+\mathbf1^\top x \\
&=\mathbf1^\top x\,.\label{eq:2}\tag2
\end{align}

Substituting back into Equation \ref{eq:1} yields

\begin{equation}
0=Px-x+\mathbf1\cdot0\implies x=Px\,.
\end{equation}

Because $P$ has a unique stationary distribution, it has a unique closed communicating class $C$. Let $x_i$ be the largest element of $x$ such that $i\in C$ and $x_j$ be an arbitrary element of $x$ such that $j\in C$. Then there exists $n$ such that $P^n_{ij}>0$, so that

\begin{align}
x=Px
&\implies x=P^nx \\
&\implies x_i=P^n_{ij}x_j+\sum_{k\in C\setminus\{j\}}P^n_{ik}x_k && C \text{ is closed} \\
&\implies x_i\le P^n_{ij}x_j+\sum_{k\in C\setminus\{j\}}P^n_{ik}x_i && x_k\le x_i\\
&\implies x_i\le P^n_{ij}x_j+(1-P^n_{ij})x_i && \sum_{k\in C}P^n_{ik}=1 \\
&\implies P^n_{ij}x_i\le P^n_{ij}x_j \\
&\implies x_i\le x_j && P^n_{ij}>0\\
&\implies x_i=x_j\,, && x_i\ge x_j
\end{align}

so for all $j\in C$, $x_j=x_i$, which we will call $r$.

For $i\notin C$, define

\begin{equation}
p^{(n)}_i=\sum_{j\in C}P^n_{ij}\,.
\end{equation}

Viewing $C$ as an absorbing set of states, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p^{(n)}_i=1$. Let $M=\max_i |x_i|$. Then $\forall i\in C$, $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists N$ such that $\left|1-p^{(N)}_i\right|<\frac\varepsilon{|r|+M+1}$, so that

\begin{align}
|x_i-r|
&=\left|P^Nx_i-r\right| \\
&=\left|\sum_{j\in C}P^N_{ij}x_j+\sum_{k\notin C}P^N_{ik}x_k-r\right| \\
&\le\left|\sum_{j\in C}P^N_{ij}x_j-r\right|+\left|\sum_{k\notin C}P^N_{ik}x_k\right| \\
&\le\left|p^{(N)}_ir-r\right|+\left|1-p^{(N)}_i\right|M && x_j=r \text{ and } |x_k|\le M \\
&= \left|1-p^{(N)}\right|(|r|+M) \\
&<\varepsilon\,.
\end{align}

Taking the limit as $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$ yields $x_i=r$. Then all elements of $x$ are equal to $r$, so by Equation \ref{eq:2},

\begin{equation}
\mathbf1^\top x=0\implies r=0\implies x=0\,.
\end{equation}

Then Equation \ref{eq:1} has only the trivial solution, so $P-I+\mathbf1\mathbf1^\top$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what $\mathbf{11}^T$ is but what might be helpful is [Gershgorin's Circle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

It might allow you to bound the eigenvalues away from zero.

Comment: in this problem, it does not guarantee, that all eigenvalues are positive or away from zero